# Prolog Calling predicates within predicates correctly

Tags: list, vector, matrix, prolog

I have two predicates in Prolog, the first one does return a correct dot product of two lists(vectors w/e) ... the second is when you take a list times a list of lists(matrix) which will return a list. The second one fails when I try to pass anything such as `([1,2],[[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]], X)`. Anyone well versed in Prolog see my mistake? I am kinda stuck since tracing and prolog itself just returns a fail all the time.

```
getDotProd([],[],0.0).
getDotProd([H1|T1],[H2|T2], N):-
    getDotProd(T1,T2,N1),
    N is N1 + (H1 * H2).



vecTimesMatrix(_,[[]],[]).
vecTimesMatrix([List], [MH|Mtail],[N]):-
    N is getDotProd(List, MH, _),
    vecTimesMatrix(List, Mtail, N).
```

Updated Code thus far now:

```
getDotProd([],[],0.0).
getDotProd([H1|T1],[H2|T2], N):-
    getDotProd(T1,T2,N1),
    N is N1 + (H1 * H2).



vecTimesMatrix([],[[]],[]).
vecTimesMatrix([List], [MH|Mtail],[N]):-
    getDotProd(List, MH, N),
    vecTimesMatrix(List, Mtail, N).
```

Comment: You have two problems. One is `N is getDotProd...`, where you mean `getDotProd(List, MH, N)`. The other is that your two rules for `getDotProd` do not have the same arity: first one has four parameters and the second has three.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, my derp haha. Thanks for the input, so like in my call on getDotProd in the 2nd predicate I just pass an N rather than setting N to the predicate? I am already not enjoying prolog that much  :/ .

Comment: Prolog is designed for symbolic computations. I guarantee you'd have more fun if you were trying to implement [symbolic differentiation](https://maheshexp.wordpress.com/2006/09/23/symbolic-computation-differential-calculus-using-prolog-part-2/) rather than linear algebra. If the goal here is to have fun with Prolog I'd pick a different problem; if the goal here is to do matrix math, I'd pick a different language--probably [Octave](https://gnu.org/software/octave/) or [Julia](http://julialang.org/).

Comment: Gotcha, yeah so far with changes made added a [] rather than _ in the first predicate of the vecTimesMatrix and fixed the other line to getDotProd(List,MH,N) .. Still on a trace it seems to accept the first call then creeps once and fails the very next time around. I will keep playing with it today though. And If I had a choice I would be doing this in C or C++.

Comment: Without the rest of the code we won't be able to help you further.

Comment: Rest of the code? That is all the code necessary to do these operations I assumed.

Comment: I see what to do. I'm pretty sure you don't want `[List]` in the second rule of `vecTimesMatrix/3`. In general, when you get a bunch of mysterious fails, it's because your rules use patterns in their heads that are excluding cases you expect them not to. Fixing this didn't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: @user3376151 the main reason newcomers to Prolog don't like the language is that they think it should be just like other languages they're familiar with but just with its own twists. When doing Prolog, however, it's best to check just about everything you know about how other languages work at the door, and learn how Prolog works as a relational language. Then you'll be able to more effectively apply it to your linear algebra problem, and as Daniel mentioned, really love it for those problems that it excels at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remaining problem is in your `vecTimesMatrix` predicate:

```
vecTimesMatrix([],[[]],[]).
vecTimesMatrix([List], [MH|Mtail],[N]):-
    getDotProd(List, MH, N),
    vecTimesMatrix(List, Mtail, N).
```

Issues:

1. In the second clause, the first argument is given as `[List]` which would imply a list of a single element (`List`). Subsequent calls to `getDotProd` and `vecTimesMatrix` in the clause indicate that this should simply be `List`.
2. In the second clause, the third argument is shown simply as a list of one argument: `[N]`. So the third argument never "builds" a list. Additionally, the recursive call to `vecTimesMatrix` has `N` as its third argument, and that argument had already been instantiated by the prior query to `getDotProd` as the dot product of the vector `List` and the vectory `MH`. Logically, the recursive call should be saying that *the vector product of `List` with `Mtail` is the tail of the final product*.
3. The base case assumes that the first argument reduces to `[]`, but this is not so. `List` always remains as-is throughout the recursive process. So instead of `[]` you should have `_` (it will keep its value, but you don't care about it in the base case).
4. The base case has as a second argument `[[]]`, but that's not the correct form for an empty list. That's actually a list consisting of one element, that element being the empty list. In reality, even though the second argument is a "list of lists", the empty list is still `[]`.

Putting it all together (and renaming predicates per *de facto* conventions using underscores rather than camel case):

```
get_dot_prod([], [], 0.0).            % Dot product of empty vectors is 0.0
                                      %   (Dot prod of vectors of unequal length
                                      %   is not defined and will fail)
get_dot_prod([H1|T1], [H2|T2], N) :-  % N is dot product of [H1|T1] [H2|T2] if...
    get_dot_prod(T1, T2, N1),         % N1 is dot product of T1 T2, and
    N is N1 + (H1 * H2).              % N is N1 + (H1*H2) [evaluated]

vec_times_matrix(_, [], []).          % Product of any vector with
                                      %   empty matrix is empty
vec_times_matrix(List, [MH|Mtail], [N|Ntail]):-
                                      % [N|Ntail] is List x [MH|Mtail] if...
    get_dot_prod(List, MH, N),        % N is dot product of List and MH, and
    vec_times_matrix(List, Mtail, Ntail). % Ntail is List x Mtail
```

This will yield:

```
| ?- vec_times_matrix([1,2],[[1,0],[0,1]], M).

M = [1.0,2.0] ? a

no
| ?- vec_times_matrix([1,2],[[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]], M).

M = [1.0,2.0,3.0] ? a

(1 ms) no
```

I added the comments in the code above to illustrate, in a simple way, how to think of the prolog predicate logic, which aids in defining them. As was pointed out already, the prolog "predicate" doesn't act as a "function". It describes a logical relation between entities which will either succeed or fail.

Once you learn to think how prolog thinks (relationally), you'll find it more enjoyable. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for going so in depth, I think after reading your answer I get it now! Good man.

Comment: I wish I could give you +10.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. First, you define both `getDotProd/4` and `getDotProd/3` predicates. The first one is a typo. I.e. you base case for the `getDotProd/3` predicate have a duplicated argument and it should be:

```
getDotProd([], [], 0).
```

Second, in the second predicate, `vecTimesMatrix/3`, you have a goal, a call to the built-in predicate `is/2`, that will cause an exception:

```
N is getDotProd(List, MH, _)
```

You cannot define your own functions on standard Prolog. You need to replace that goal with:

```
getDotProd(List, MH, N)
```

There are other problems but this should help you progress.

Comment: Ahh that was supposed to be 0.0 and is correct in my actual code to be a float returned, typing up my code quickly on another computer I made a typo.